# Why can you not return an object to Javascript's Array.map() and it map it properly?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, dictionary

I have two functions below (they are taken out of a larger script so assume everything is defined etc. `self.sentenceObjs` works great. It returns an object exactly like it's supposed to do. `self.parseBodySections` for some reason sets `bodyJSON` to an array of `undefined` even though `self.sentenceObjs` is returning perfect objects given the `dom` array of objects I want mapped. For some reason when I run `dom.map(self.sentenceObjs)` it returns undefined for each object. Any idea why this would be? Is there something with `Array.map()` that I missing?

```
  self.parseBodySections = function(dom, cb) {
    var bodyJSON = dom.map(self.sentenceObjs);
    console.log(bodyJSON); // prints: [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]

    return cb(null, bodyJSON);
  };

  self.sentenceObjs = function(section) {
    var paragraphToTextAndLinks = function(cb) {
      return self.paragraphToTextAndLinks(section.children, function(err, paragraphText, links) {
        if (err) {
          return cb(err);
        }

        return cb(null, paragraphText, links);
      });
    };

    return async.waterfall([
      paragraphToTextAndLinks,
      self.paragraphToSentences
    ],
    function(err, sentences, paragraphPlaintext) {
      var paragraph = {
        type: section.name,
        value: paragraphPlaintext,
        children: sentences
      };

      console.log(paragraph) // prints perfect object (too long to show here)

      return paragraph;
    });
  };
```

Comment: What does `waterfall` return? I'm not very familiar with the library but by reading at the docs it seems like it doesn't actually return the compound of the functions, it exposes it into a callback. Can you check `console.log(async.waterfall([...` and see what it outputs?

Comment: Please post a short, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @elclanrs Yeah I think it's something with that because it returns `undefined`. I'm pretty new to the library myself so I'm probably misunderstanding something.

Comment: I think you just need to run `parseBodySections` _inside_ the callback of `waterfall`, not the other way around, since `waterfall` is the asynchronous part. I may be wrong tho...

Comment: @elclanrs yeah that sounds like it might solve the issue. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you return "paragraph" in the callback function of waterfall.
So the function sentenceObjs returns nothing, or undefined.

You need to pass in a callback function to sentenceObjs and call async.map instead of Array.map:

```
self.parseBodySections = function(dom, cb) {
  async.map(dom, self.sentenceObjs, function(err, bodyJSON) {
    console.log(bodyJSON); // prints: [ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
    return cb(null, bodyJSON);
  });
};

self.sentenceObjs = function(section, cb) {
  var paragraphToTextAndLinks = function(cb) {
    return self.paragraphToTextAndLinks(section.children, function(err, paragraphText, links) {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }

      return cb(null, paragraphText, links);
    });
  };

  return async.waterfall([
    paragraphToTextAndLinks,
    self.paragraphToSentences
  ],
  function(err, sentences, paragraphPlaintext) {
    var paragraph = {
      type: section.name,
      value: paragraphPlaintext,
      children: sentences
    };

    console.log(paragraph); // prints perfect object (too long to show here)

    return cb(null, paragraph);
  });
};
```