# Why does Javascript .map() return and extra "undefined" for an object of strings?

Tags: javascript

Please can anyone help with where an undefined item is coming from when mapping an object of strings. This is my object followed by the mapping:

```
function giveAdminTasks(){
var item;
var arr = [{adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 0},
   {adminTask: "Study",lessonNo: 27},
   {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 3},
   {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3},
   {adminTask:"Calling Record",lessonNo: 3}];

 arr.map(function(elem){
 if(elem.lessonNo === 3){
 item += " + " + elem.adminTask;
 } 
})
console.log(item);
}
```

However, this returns a variable that looks like this:

"undefined + Print Certificate + Calling Record + Calling Record"

I can't figure out where the "undefined" item comes from. This doesn't happen if I just map the object without the "if" statement. Can anyone help?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181238/why-can-you-not-return-an-object-to-javascripts-array-map-and-it-map-it-prope) talks about map only working on strings, but my object is all strings.

Answer (score 4):

You did not initialize your `item` variable thus it has an initial value of `undefined`.

Change this:

```
var item;
```

to this:

```
var item = "";
```

You also have to deal with the fact that `item` is initially empty and you don't want to add a leading `+` sign when it's empty.

---

FYI, this is really a misuse of `.map()`.  You should be using `.forEach()` or one of the other iterators instead since you aren't interested in a returned array.

```
function giveAdminTasks() {
    var item = "";
    var arr = [
        {adminTask: "Print Certificate", lessonNo: 0}, 
        {adminTask: "Study", lessonNo: 27}, 
        {adminTask: "Print Certificate", lessonNo: 3}, 
        {adminTask: "Calling Record", lessonNo: 3}, 
        {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3
    }];

    arr.forEach(function(elem) {
        if (elem.lessonNo === 3) {
            if (item) item += " + ";
            item += elem.adminTask;
        }
    });
    console.log(item);
}
```

You could also use `.reduce()` like this:

```
var item = arr.reduce(function(str, item) {
    if (item.lessonNo === 3) {
        if (str) str += " + ";
        str += elem.adminTask;
    }
    return str;
}, "");
console.log(item);
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Comment to explain?  What is not correct about this?

Comment: You had my upvote until the code was posted. You are correct that this is a misuse of `map` but I'd also say this is a misuse of `forEach` because what you're actually doing is a fold (or "reduce"). The result is something that is needlessly complicated and littered with hard-to-read code: like nested `if` that does a null-check on `item`... way too hands-on

Comment: @naomik - This code is completely correct and works just fine.  You are free to post a different answer and campaign that yours is better, but downvotes are typically reserved for incorrect answers, not answers that you just think there's a better way to do it.  FYI, I also included a `.reduce()` solution.  I didn't downvote yours for needlessly making a new array on every iteration of the loop.  I commented on that fact instead.  And, you say my code is needlessly complicated?  Weird.  In many ways, it's more straightforward than either of yours, particular for beginning JS users.

Comment: I have removed the downvote. Correctness covers more than just the output of an answer. To me, it includes everything else you're saying with it. And by demonstrating a solution in a particular way, you implicitly recommend the techniques you're using within.

Comment: @naomik - Well, there are many ways to solve this.  I've shown two, you've shown two and Oriol has shown one.  All are technically correct and work just fine.  It is a pure matter of opinion which are "best".  The OP and others can vote on what they like best.  I went for the solutions that I thought would be the simplest step from what the OP already had in the theory that that might be the easiest step for the OP (who appears to be a bit of a beginner) to learn and understand, even though they are somewhat simpler.  There are many different approaches.

Comment: @Supertopoz - Did you get your question answered?  If so, please select the best answer and click the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate that your question has been answered and this will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more declarative solution using ES6. It's most similar to Oriol's solution but doesn't iterate through the data more than once.

```js
const giveAdminTasks = (data, n) =>
  data.reduce((acc, {adminTask, lessonNo}) =>
    lessonNo === n ? [...acc, adminTask] : acc, []).join(' + ')

let arr = [
   {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 0},
   {adminTask: "Study",lessonNo: 27},
   {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 3},
   {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3},
   {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3}
]

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 3))
// Print Certificate + Calling Record + Calling Record

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 0))
// Print Certificate
 
console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 27))
// Study
```

And the ES5 equivalent

```js
function giveAdminTasks (data, n) {
  return data.reduce(function (acc, x) {
    return x.lessonNo === n
      ? acc.concat([x.adminTask])
      : acc
  }, []).join(' + ')
}

var arr = [
  {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 0},
  {adminTask: "Study",lessonNo: 27},
  {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 3},
  {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3},
  {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3}
]

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 3))
// Print Certificate + Calling Record + Calling Record

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 0))
// Print Certificate

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 27))
// Study
```

---

To address @jfriend00's comment, to preserve the readability of the code and prevent the needless creation of extra arrays, you can introduce a small helper function.

At this point, I would call this a premature optimization. It's likely the original code will meet your needs unless you have significantly large datasets. If you run a profiler on your code and notice that this bit of code is slowing you down, then it might be time to start making some adjustments …

```js
const apush = (xs,x) => (xs.push(x), xs)

const giveAdminTasks = (data, n) =>
  data.reduce((acc, {adminTask, lessonNo}) =>
    lessonNo === 3 ? apush(acc, adminTask) : acc, []).join(' + ')

let arr = [
  {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 0},
  {adminTask: "Study",lessonNo: 27},
  {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 3},
  {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3},
  {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3}
]

console.log(giveAdminTasks(arr, 3))
// Print Certificate + Calling Record + Calling Record
```

Comment: Why `acc.concat()` instead of `acc.push()`?  Why make a new array on every iteration?

Comment: It's about writing an expression that represents your intention. If `acc.push(adminTask)` returned the target array, then it could trade places with `acc.concat([adminTask])` – however for some reason `.push` returns the new length of the array which makes it a confusing expression. I avoid confusion even if it's at the cost of making a new array.

Comment: *"Why make a new array on every iteration?"* is in the same vein as "What about performance/speed/efficiency?" – to which my response will always be: speed/efficiency is not the only metric used to measure the quality of code.

Comment: Yeah, but needlessly creating a new array on every iteration is a bit hard to defend in my opinion.  That's not just a few lines of JS code, that's allocating memory and copying a previous array to it.  And, it doesn't make the code simpler to understand in my opinion.  This is opinion so we can agree to disagree.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `filter`, `map` and `join`:

```js
var arr = [{adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 0},
           {adminTask: "Study",lessonNo: 27},
           {adminTask: "Print Certificate",lessonNo: 3},
           {adminTask: "Calling Record",lessonNo: 3},
           {adminTask:"Calling Record",lessonNo: 3}];
var item = arr.filter(function(elem){
  return elem.lessonNo === 3;
}).map(function(elem){
  return elem.adminTask;
}).join(' + ');
console.log(item);
```

Comment: Why create two intermediate arrays that you don't need?

Comment: @jfriend00 Because it's more descriptive like this, and because there is no filterMap method. Joining the array may perform better than lots of string concatenations.

Comment: I don't think this is really about performance, but you aren't doing yourself any performance favors by creating two additional arrays.  `.join()` is handy here, but I'm not sure it's worth all the extra overhead to get to it.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would argue he/she has done himself/herself a favour by limiting their exposure to unnecessary complexity